# How to delete the top space of a div when the other one is larger?

Tags: css, position

I'm building a website with two calendars, but I'm having some troubles with their position.

Everything seems to look fine till I change to a month that has a larger number of weeks, September for instance. So then the calendar is larger and it adds an unnecessary space on the other calendar:

[image: calendar1]

html file:

```
<div class="container">
  <div id="calendar1">
    <div class="vcal1-header">
      <button class="vcal1-btn" data-calendar1-toggle="previous">
        <svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M20,11V13H8L13.5,18.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L13.5,5.5L8,11H20Z"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="vcal1-header__label" data-calendar1-label="month"></div>
      <button class="vcal1-btn" data-calendar1-toggle="next">
        <svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="vcal1-week">
      <span>Dl</span>
      <span>Dt</span>
      <span>Dc</span>
      <span>Dj</span>
      <span>Dv</span>
      <span>Ds</span>
      <span>Dg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="vcal1-body" data-calendar1-area="month"></div>
  </div>
  <div id="calendar2">
    <div class="vcal2-header">
      <button class="vcal2-btn" data-calendar2-toggle="previous">
        <svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M20,11V13H8L13.5,18.5L12.08,19.92L4.16,12L12.08,4.08L13.5,5.5L8,11H20Z"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
      <div class="vcal2-header__label" data-calendar2-label="month"></div>
      <button class="vcal2-btn" data-calendar2-toggle="next">
        <svg height="24" version="1.1" viewbox="0 0 24 24" width="24" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
          <path d="M4,11V13H16L10.5,18.5L11.92,19.92L19.84,12L11.92,4.08L10.5,5.5L16,11H4Z"></path>
        </svg>
      </button>
    </div>
    <div class="vcal2-week">
      <span>Dl</span>
      <span>Dt</span>
      <span>Dc</span>
      <span>Dj</span>
      <span>Dv</span>
      <span>Ds</span>
      <span>Dg</span>
    </div>
    <div class="vcal2-body" data-calendar2-area="month"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css file:

```
.container {
  text-align: center;
  margin: auto;
  margin: 10rem auto;
  max-width: 50%;
  min-height: 45vh;
}

.container #calendar1, .container #calendar2 {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  max-width: 45%;
  text-align: center;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

I have tried to define a top-margin: 0px on each of them, but it didn't work.

The calendar also uses a JavaScript file, but I don't think it's really needed to post it here since my issue related to HTML/CSS.

This is how it should look everytime, with no space on their top. I'd like to have a space on their bottom instead:

[image: calendar1]

How can I fix this? Thank you in advance!

Comment: Try adding `vertical-align:top` to your calendars.

Comment: Thank you Paulie. It worked!